# Python Subversion bindings which package nicely with `pip`?

Tags: python, svn, pip

Are there any usable/documented Python bindings for Subversion that package nicely using `pip`?

I'm primarily concerned with adding the bindings to a virtual environment.  My goal is to be able to do something like `pip install <pkg>`.

Packages I've tried:

- `pysvn`
- `svn`
- `subvertpy`

Of these, `subvertpy` is the only that is on pypi and installs cleanly.  Unfortunately, the documentation/usability of this package is *terrible*.

Comment: @Joao: If that would work, the question would be senseless. Hint: It doesn't.

Comment: Regarding the question: Why does it have to be `pip`? I don't think you'll get an answer that way.

Comment: Niklas, precisely. Was trying to shed some light over the question's goal.

Comment: @Niklas - what other tools might work?  Something like `easy_install`?

Comment: @JoaoFigueiredo - updated the question with that goal.

Comment: @sholsapp: a simple `setup.py install` will probably work. Might also be that your package manager provides a package for it, which would be even better. For Ubuntu, try `sudo apt-get install python-subversion`

Comment: @NiklasB.: That does work, but I need to be able to release a self-contained package to production machines.  That is why I need the module put into my virtual environment.  I'm pretty sure that `pip` can take the URL of a Python package and install it with `setup.py install`.  I'll have to try that and update the post.

Comment: @sholsapp: Yes, that's what I'm doing with a project of mine, which is not in the repos. I just put the code with a `setup.py` at the root into Git. Afterwards you can do `sudo pip install git+git://github.com/niklasb/webkit-server.git`. This does also work with requirements files (`pip -r requirements.txt`, see https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape/blob/master/requirements.txt for an example). Problem is, however, that non-pure packages usually have non-Python dependencies, which need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that neither of the packages you mention are in pypi so pip can find them. There is a package called subvertpy which is in pypi so can be installed easily with pip the details of the package are here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/subvertpy/0.8.10

https://launchpad.net/subvertpy

However it does have some prerequisites that you must install first (SVN developer packages) so it may not suit you if you need a completely atomic pip install. Then again if you already have those libraries installed or you are willing to install the prerequisites once because you plan to use pip to install subvertpy into several virtual envs then it may be worth looking at. I haven't used subvertpy so I can't say how it compares to the other packages but given your requirement for pip install it might suit you.